# ListBox gets wrong selected value, how can i get the correct value?

Tags: selecteditem, listboxitem, selectedvalue

I have a listbox that has the following items and values right now.

Items, Misc. Charge/Taxes/Labor Charges

Value,  50.00/50.00/100.00

The problem is when i select the taxes item, it will turn it into Misc. Charges because they have the same value.  Is it possible to have the listbox get the correct item and value if the values are the same??

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is out of context and thus makes no sense. We don't know which language and/or system you are talking about, among other things. Some code won't hurt either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value attribute as the unique id (miscCharge, Taxes) and the text attribute as what is displayed to the user (50.00, 50.00).

```
<asp:ListItem value="item1" Text="50" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem value="item2" Text="50"></asp:ListItem>

ListItem selectedItem = list1.SelectedItem;
string id = list1.SelectedItem.Value;
string text = list1.SelectedItem.Text;
```